# Disable/filter any touch event for a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, touch-event

Is it possible to disable Touch events for all the views inside a Layout by targetting the ParentLayout. I know this is possible by going through each individual view contained in the Layout but it would be very helpful if there was a way to do it for complete Layout. I have already tried the following but all in vain.

```
ParentLayout.setClickable(false);

ParentLayout.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(event);

ParentLayout.onTouchEvent(event);

ParentLayout.setOnTouchListener(l);
...
```

and others in similar fashion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Disable all touch event in parent view. `dispatchTouchEvent()` and
   `onInterceptTouchEvent()` can all achieve this goal.
2. Set `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to all child view, and set
   parent `android:enable="false"`

Answer (score 2):

Consider taking following approach.

```
 public void disableTouch(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        view.setClickable(false);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            disableTouch((ViewGroup) view);
        }
    }
}
```

It will traverse through all Child and disable touch event for each of them.

Comment: In order to implement infinte scrolling, my ViewPager has very large number of items. 2147483647 to be precise. This code will probably go through all those items and won't be feasible.

Comment: OMG! 2147483647 nos of views.!!

Comment: All are not activated at once, only the ones needed are instanciated and deleted soon. This number is only the number of positions reserved for views. Thats why i am looking for something that does it in one go.

Comment: Take relative layout as parent,Have one transparent imageview over your different parent layout and catch the clicks on it and not on the views.. :D

Comment: And he never got back.